# Is there a way I can collect all instanciated objects together to an ArrayList without knowing the number of objects there is?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
        //Origin, Destination, Date of Dept, Time of Dept, Date of Arr, Time of Arri, Fare, Seats, Unique ID.
        Trip t1 = new Trip("City1", "City2", "18-12-20", "10:00", "18-12-20", "12:30", 23, 50, 1);
        Trip t2 = new Trip("City2", "City1", "18-12-20", "13:00", "18-12-20", "15:30", 25, 50, 2);
        Trip t3 = new Trip("City3", "City4", "18-12-20", "10:15", "18-12-20", "11:45", 12, 40, 3);
        Trip t4 = new Trip("City4", "City3", "18-12-20", "12:15", "18-12-20", "13:45", 12, 40, 4);
```

Is there a way, I can store all these objects into an ArrayList without knowing the number of objects there may be?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<>();
trips.add(new Trip("City1", "City2", "18-12-20", "10:00", "18-12-20", "12:30", 23, 50, 1));
trips.add(new Trip("City2", "City1", "18-12-20", "13:00", "18-12-20", "15:30", 25, 50, 2));
..
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to just add all available trip objects to the arraylist at once without have a bunch of `.add()` s. Thats good though thanks. @sotix

Comment: @alienware13user `Arrays.asList(new Trip(..), new Trip(..))` can do that

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` automatically resizes itself as you add more data, so you don't need to know the number of objects in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add all the trips into the arraylist all at once , then you can do this

```
List<Trip> trips = Arrays.asList(t1,t2,t3,t4)
```